# Where to get spatial data for ATC airspace?

Tags: air-traffic-control, datasets

I am looking for free or open spatial vector data (geoJson, .shp, .kml, …) which maps the responsibilities of air traffic control in South East Asia, worldwide would be very nice too. [SkyVector.com](https://skyvector.com/) seems to have an excellent data source but its not open. any ideas? Cheers!

[image]

Comment: "*which maps the responsibilities of air traffic control*": Can you be more explicit in what you're searching for? Down to which level? See also: [ICAO maps](https://gis.icao.int/gallery/) and [ICAO viewer](https://gis.icao.int/icaoviewer/).

Comment: I think the OP is looking for ATC sector data. In other words, what data delineates between FIRs, center/control, and airspace, and perhaps even different frequency sectors. Clarification on what the OP is looking for would be helpful.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, non aviator here :). I am looking for polygons which represent the areas of responsibility for air traffic control. I added an screenshot to my question to illustrate that (andaman sea of the coast of thailand with the highlighted areas of my interest). thanks for the links, looks promising but might take me a while to dig through

Answer (score 3):

Data about ATC sectors in easy to use format, such as shapefiles, is generally *not publically available*. Take it from someone who has spent hundreds of hours manually importing such data from PDF text files to various GIS applications. You can find a few individual data sources here and there via Google, but they are limited geographically and more often than not, outdated.

What you need to do is locate the aeronautical information publication (AIP) of your country of interest, and navigate to the En-route section. Airspace data is usually contained in section ENR 2.1. What you will find is a more or less well formatted PDF file containing textual airspace definitions (WGS-84 based coordinates). You will need to manually transfer this text data into which ever format you need, using your preferred text editor or spreadsheet application.

Comment: Can I please ask how often are these definitions expected to be updated?

Comment: @A_A Depends on what you want to use the data for. Airspaces can be changed as often as every 28 days

Comment: Thank you. Personal curiosity. 28 days is an impressively short interval, for me anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting answer, I see if this is suitable for my purpose, which is doing maps (non aviation maps)